# Convergence of specific sequence in reduced group algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras, schauder-basis

I have $B = C_r^* (S_\infty)$ - reduced group algebra of permutation group of naturam numbers fixing all but a finite number of element. $B$ have countable family of subalgebras: $B_n = C_r^* (S_n)$ and I have sequence of elements $x_n \in B_n \setminus B_{n-1}$. Is it true that convergence of norms of partial sums $||x_1 + ... + x_n||$ implies convergence of series $x_1+x_2+x_3+...$ ?

It may be true because $x_n/||x_n||$ is Schauder basis of linear span of $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ What are you think about that? Any remarks, allusions and intuitive arguments are welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: It's not even true in a finite dimensional space. The partial sums could have constant norm and still not converge.

Comment: I put some restrictions on $x_n$ which can be sufficient. For example, for basis in $\ell_1$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $B_n$ can be seen as $M_n(\mathbb C)$, with the embeddings $$\gamma_{n,n+1}:X\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}B&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Let $\{e_{kj}^{(n)}\}$ denote the matrix units of $M_n(\mathbb C)$, and define $x_n=e_{nn}$. Then, for all $n$,
$$
\|x_1+\cdots+x_n\|=1,
$$
while $$\|(x_1+\cdots+x_m)-(x_1+\cdots+x_n)\|=1$$ if $m\ne n$.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand how you represent $B_n$ as  $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, for example $B_2$ have only two linear independent elements: identity and transposition, but $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ have 4 linear independent elements. Can you explain?

Comment: Yes, I need to be more careful about that, I guess; I'll think about it. But it doesn't really matter, because in any case the $B_n$ are finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras, so they always have projections to play the game above.

Comment: But I have some restriction that $x_n \notin B_{n-1}$, so we restrict our possible choose to some small linear subspace. For example $B_2 \setminus B_1$ doesnt have any projections. I intuitively agree that it is false, but I want to believe (:

Comment: If you have a proper inclusion $A\subset B$ of finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebras, there is always a projection in $B\setminus A$.

Comment: Ok, now I see that I ask that I dont really want :) I mean that $P_k(x_n)=0$ where $k<n$ and $P_k$ is projector on $C_r^*(S_k)$. So $x_2 = T_1$ - is correct, but $x_2 = T_1 + 1$ - dont. I will ask a new question, thanks. ($T_1$ - is transposition)