# Convergence of specific sequence in specific reduced group algebra equivalent to convergence of norms

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, c-star-algebras, schauder-basis

Let $A = C_r^*(S_\infty)$ where $S_\infty$ - is permutation group of natural numbers fixing all but a finite number of element. Let $A_n = C_r^*(S_n)$ - subspaces of $A$ and $P_n : A \to A$ is projector on $A_n$.

I have sequence $x_n \in A_n$ for which $P_{n-1}(x_n) = 0$, $P_{n+1} (x_n) = x_n$.

Is it true, that convergence of norms of partial sums $\|x_1 + ... + x_n\|$ implies convergence of partial sums $x_1 + ... + x_n$?

I have [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817685/convergence-of-specific-sequence-in-reduced-group-algebra) before. But that question is more specific and more nontrivial (maybe). Any remarks, allusions and intuitive arguments are welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by the projection on $A_n$?

Comment: I mean operator which sends all words, which contains $T_i, i > n$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proper inclusions of finite-dimensional C $^*$-algebras  $$\tag{1}A_1\subset A_2\subset\cdots $$ embedded in a unital way.

Each of these is a direct sum of full matrix algebras, and the embeddings are tracked by the Bratelli diagram. By looking at a single path in the diagram, we get an inclusion  $$\tag{2} M_{n_1}(\mathbb C)\hookrightarrow M_{n_2}(\mathbb C)\hookrightarrow \cdots$$ with $n_k|n_{k+1} $ and the embeddings of the form $$\tag{3} a\longmapsto a\oplus\cdots \oplus a . $$ The restriction of the canonical conditional expectation is "compression to the  (block) diagonal".

Note that because the dimensions of $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are always properly increasing, we may assume that the path chosen in $(2)$ produces increasing sizes of the blocks ($n_k<n_{k+1}$), if necessary by taking a subsequence; if all paths were bounded in dimension, then the direct limit $\varinjlim A_n$ would be finite-dimensional.

With $e_{kj}^{m} $ the canonical matrix units of $M_m(\mathbb C)$, let $x_k=e_{k,n_k}^k $. Because  of the form of the embeddings $(3)$, the first row elements are shared between the algebras, i.e. $$ e^k_{k,j}=e^h_{k,j},\ \ \ \text{ if }\ h\geq k. $$ As the conditional expectation is compression, $P_{n-1}(e_{k,n_k}^k)=0$ if $k> n-1$.

Now, 
\begin{align}
\|x_1+\cdots+x_n\|^2&=\|(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^*(x_1+\cdots+x_n)\|\\ \ \\
&=\left\|\sum_{k,j=1}^n x_k^*x_j\right\|
=\left\|\sum_{k,j=1}^n e_{n_k,k}e_{j,n_j}\right\|\\ \ \\
&=\left\| \sum_{k=1}^n e_{n_k,n_k}\right\|=1.
\end{align}
Finally, 
$$
\|(x_1+\cdots+x_{n+1})-(x_1+\cdots+x_n)\|=\|x_{n+1}\|=1,
$$
so the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy.

Comment: But it is not example in $C_r^*(S_\infty)$ algebra, isn't it?

Comment: Why not? $\ \ $

Comment: Why you decide that inductive limit of matrix algebras isomorphic to $C_r^*(S_\infty)$?

Comment: I haven't thought about group algebras in a long time, but if I'm not wrong, from $S_\infty=\bigcup_nS_n$ it follows that $C^*_r(S_\infty)$ is the inductive limit of $C^*_r(S_n)$. If it isn't, then of course my argument does not apply.

Comment: But why $C_r^*(S_n)$ is isomorphic to $M_{n1}(\mathbb{C})$? Why not $M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C}) \oplus M_{n_2}(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Oh, I see. You are not reading my answer carefully. I wrote "By looking at a single path in the diagram..." I'm not saying that $A_n\subset A_{n+1}$ is an inclusion $M_{n_1}(\mathbb C)\subset M_{n_2}(\mathbb C)$; but it contains such an inclusion.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry I was not clear enough.